# HTTP requests directly to pod in k8s cluster using k8s go-client

Tags: go, kubernetes-go-client

What I need to do is to make request without forwarding the port to the HTTP server located in k8s pod.

I have tried to make this request:

```
res := clientset.CoreV1().RESTClient().Get().
    Namespace("default").
    Resource("pods").
    Name("my_pod_name:8080").
    SubResource("proxy").
    Suffix("api").
    Do(context.Background())
```

and it is working for simple HTTP GET but I also need to pass headers and query parameters and I cannot do it using `SetHeader`.

Does a better solution/client exist for that case?

Comment: Do you need to do this using the control-plane? Why not a http-request directly?

Comment: This service cannot by deployed in cluster, so I cannot do this directly. Outside the cluster I can forward port but it is not preferable for me.

Comment: If you want to send HTTP request to Pod directly, then **you will need to create a K8s service which routes traffic to it. To expose the service outside of the cluster, add an ingress resource**. Otherwise, you will always have to run port-forward command 1st in order to connect. 

Check out these links (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ & https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Comment: I agree with that but this service cannot be exposed outside cluster and connection to it is only needed for maintenance. These solutions are known for me but I just wanted to extend this basic operation in k8s go-client (presented in question) which is working for very simple GET. I just need to extend it to add headers and query params.

Comment: if sdk has not enough fine grained config. Do a normal http request. All you need to do is include the service account token. Its set as bearer header if I recall correctly.